# Favicon does not work with SSL

Tags: html, ssl, favicon

I have a website on a SSL host. It has a favicon which is referenced by a domain-relative URL:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/contextpath/favicon.ico"/>
```

When SSL is off, it works, but when SSL is on, it doesn't work. 
How can I get favicon to work with SSL?

Comment: Which browser(s)? Which version(s)? Where do you expect the favicon to show (tab or location bar)?

Comment: Chrome, FireFox (last versions). Need it in location bar, instead of lock icon of SSL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, favicons have been removed from the location bar [in recent versions of Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/ux/2012/06/site-identity-ui-updates/). This is mainly to prevent downgrade attacks where the attacker is able to provide a favicon looking like a lock, thereby making the user believe that they're using HTTPS when they're not.