# Favicon is not showing if the URL starts with https://

Tags: favicon

I am facing one issue with favicon.ico.  Here is my link rel code which has been included in header portion.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />`

The problem is, I can view the favicon in all browsers if the url starts with http://. When the address starts with https://, the favicon is not showing in IE browser.  Is there anything that I need to do?  Did I miss anything important to include?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154986/favicon-does-not-work-with-ssl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324456/favicon-not-showing-up

Comment: Could you give the URL of your site for analysis?

Comment: Actually the url can't be viewable out of our closed secured network.  Sorry.  Let me know if you can able to figure out what might be the root cause of above mentioned issue.  Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it by putting the following line in the head section of my html file:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
```