# Favicon location ignored by chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

I am using following code to display favicon.ico:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://{domain}/res/202009100200/images/favicon/en/favicon.ico"/>
```

Using this URL favicon.ico loads correctly. But Chrome does not show any favicon and if I inspect via Development console I realize it tries to load favicon from site's root (where it obviusly does not exist).

Why is Chrome trying to find favicon in site's root instead of the location I provide? In Firefox and Edge it works.

Comment: Just put it in the default locatjon. It's not a good idea not to.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359390/9436078

Comment: I am determining favicon according to many parameters so that's the reason I need two favicons in different folders.

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy please check this refrence https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300856/favicon-is-not-showing-if-the-url-starts-with-https

Answer (score -1):

you can use this code

```
<link rel="icon" href="icon.gif" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">
```

It is working when I use

Answer (score -1):

Most of time browser use the favicon location as root directory not the directory specified in href attribute. Try to Putting favicon at root directory.

I all refer to go to this  Favicon location ignored by chrome an already active question with many answers hope it help.

Comment: So what is the purpose of href attribute if it is ignored?

Comment: it does ignore but not every time i have an website [link](https://openlibrary.site) i also have placed my favicon at a subdirectory "root/img/favicon.ico" but it works fine. it does matter of browser(try to upgrade to new one)